# integration using residue theory

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the value of the integral $\int_{c}\frac{3z^2+2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)}$ around the circle $c:|z-2| = 2$

In the answer I got $\operatorname{Res}_{z=1} \frac{z^3+2}{z^2+9} = \frac12$ 
 
 
therefore the integration is equal to $2\pi i*\frac1{2} = \pi i$

but how do we get $(z^3+2)/(z^2+9)$ ?

I remember that the residue theory is $\int_{c}f(z)dz = 2\pi i ∑\operatorname{Res}_{z_{k}}f(z)$
 
 
I think this problem has applied this theory, but I don't know how to get the Residue of $f(z)$

Comment: Note that $\pm3i$, the roots of $z^2+9$, are not in the region with border $c$. So, they aren't included in the residue computation.

Comment: $\pi i$ is the correct answer. The only pole inside the contour is $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=1}\frac{3z^2+2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)}&=\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)\frac{3z^2+2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)}\\&=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{3z^2+2}{z^2+9}\\&=\frac12.\end{align}